# Remove blank line in c++

Tags: c++

**How to remover blank lines after reading a text file using c++?**

```
while(arry[i]="/n"){
        i++;
    }
```

This is my code.It gives some output.But it is not a expected output.

Comment: At least 2 issues there: `=` and `/n`...

Comment: yea (==) instead of (=) and why /n?

Comment: Without more code we can't be sure whether you mean `"/n"` (some odd string) or `'\n'`(the newline char(

Comment: "`It gives some output.But it is not a expected output.`" - but I am not going to tell you what that output was ;-)  Sorry, just joking. Welcome aboard, but please read [ask].  That output could help, so the more info you give in future, the better that we can help you. good luck :-)

Comment: Also, that code will not give any output. If output concerns you, please post more code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
while (arry[i] == '\r' || arry[i] == '\n') {
    i++;
}
```

And please add the checkpoint of the boundary of arry like that:

```
i < arry.length()
```

`\r` is a carriage return character; it tells your terminal emulator to move the cursor at the start of the line. So, `\r` allows to override the current line of the terminal emulator.
In C++ single quotes identify a single character, while double quotes create a string literal. `'a'` is a single a character literal, while `"a"` is a string literal containing an `'a'` and a `null terminator`

Comment: Good answer but you could improve it by explaining a bit more. Why single quote instead of double, why checking `\r` and `\n`..

Comment: while loop contain logical condition.So using (==)

Comment: @John3136 "" for the string, '' for the character. We check the blank line by the character end-of-line '\n' and the new line '\r'.
Depending the system, maybe single character '\r' or '\n', or both use to define a end-of-current-line and begin new line.

Comment: @HiepNguyen Yes, I know all of that but you should edit your answer to include that info as it certainly looks like the person asking the question doesn't know it.